# dns and error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web

Today I am experiencing a big problem with 502 error.
Here is details:
on azure website it works perfectly when I use: http://mywebsite.cloudapp.net/
but when I point dns on http://www.mywebsite.com some actions (not all) returned 502 errors. It is weird because when I use the same actions on http://mywebsite.cloudapp.net/ it works perfectly.

Note: "mywebsite" it is fake name of the website.

Please help

Can it be some problems with proxy or so?

---

UPDATE:
I notice that it happens with "PUT" command, with "GET" for other requests it works. Can the problem be with "PUT" command and some DNS settings? Or proxy?

Here is the response from the server:

```
"response": {
  "status": 502,
  "statusText": "Bad Gateway",
  "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
  "headers": [
    {
      "name": "Date",
      "value": "Sat, 06 Apr 2013 18:33:08 GMT"
    },
    {
      "name": "Server",
      "value": "Microsoft-IIS/7.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "X-Powered-By",
      "value": "ASP.NET"
    },
    {
      "name": "Content-Length",
      "value": "1477"
    },
    {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "text/html"
    }
  ],
  "cookies": [],
  "content": {
    "size": 1477,
    "mimeType": "text/html",
    "compression": 0,
    "text": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</h2>\r\n  <h3>There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  },
  "redirectURL": "",
  "headersSize": 162,
  "bodySize": 1477
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.
Just in godaddy was incorrect setup for DNS. I had to setup IP address for azure webrole (NOT WEBSITE) in the "A" records. Now it works perfectly.